# Ubuntu not working properly on Asus laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, laptop, asus

I got an Asus F550V (i7 Quad 8GB DDR4 nVidia GTX 950M) laptop from work today, and it came with Free-Dos.

I managed to install Ubuntu 16.04 but the cooler keeps working on maximum for no reason. I just started it and it keeps at high without anything working in the background.

Does anyone has any idea? I'm holding my urge to smash this laptop. It works like a charm on Windows 10, and nothing else. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the fan speed  of a laptop is controlled by the BIOS, which reads a value to determine the thermal profile to use. In my case, the value is stored here : /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/thermal_control. It is a file that has either 0, 1 or 2 in it, for respectively performance, balanced or silent mode. Maybe you have something similar on your device.

Comment: it s not just the fan, ubuntu crashes when i hit apt update. it work ok, but when i reboot the hole system crashes and it wont work again, not in recovery or safe mode or whatever..